# Textfield frame animation is not in sync with keyboard animation duration

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, nsnotificationcenter

I have a text field and I am able to move it up a with keyboard. However, the animation is not in sync. The textfield frame moves up about .5 second ahead of keyboard duration. I think they should be in sync but I'm not able to figure out the problem. Below is my keyboard function animation.

Notification observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

Animation func:

```
    @objc func handleKeyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue, let keyboardDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double, let tabBarHeight = tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height{
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height

        UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardDuration, animations: {
                    self.textfieldBottomeConstraint?.constant = -keyboardHeight + tabBarHeight
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }

}
```

I did try this but still get the same results:

```
self.textfieldBottomeConstraint?.constant = -keyboardHeight + tabBarHeight

UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardDuration, animations: {

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

})
```

Comment: You need to keep the curves in sync also. See `UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey`

Comment: I think because you add tabBarHeight to the height , so animation duration is not correct

Comment: I also removed tab bar height to test but still get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Two things to try:

1. Try using `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame` instead of `UIKeyboardWillShow`
2. If it does not change anything, try using the keyboard curve inside your animation.

   ```
   UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
   UIView.setAnimationCurve(context.animationCurve)
   UIView.setAnimationDuration(context.animationDuration)
   ```

   where curve and duration are

   ```
   public var animationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurve {
       let value = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber
       return UIViewAnimationCurve(rawValue: value.intValue)!
   }

   public var animationDuration: Double {
       return userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard notification also includes a 
`UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey` and a `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey`. You can interrogate those values to make sure your animation uses the same duration and animation curve that the keyboard uses. (Search on "Keyboard Notification User Info Keys" in the Xcode help system to find all the different key/value pairs provided in keyboard notifications.

Comment: The code in the question is already getting and using the `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` value.

Comment: Oh, so it is. That bit was off the right edge of the text view so I missed it and assumed that `keyboardDuration` was a constant.